# Mongoose validation Error when seeting up relations

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose and trying to setup relation between two schemas but I am getting ValidationError

```
 errors: {
    userId: ValidatorError: Path `userId` is required.
        at validate (C:\ShoppingApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1222:13)
        at C:\ShoppingApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1205:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\ShoppingApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1150:14)
        at C:\ShoppingApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2439:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
        at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
        at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:429:9) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'userId',
      value: null,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'Product validation failed'
}
Error: Product validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (C:\ShoppingApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)       
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:698:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:269:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1870:40)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:281:10)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:291:61)
    at C:\ShoppingApp\controllers\admin.js:26:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:429:9) {
```

And Here is my both schemas files:-

Product Schema File:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const productSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

User Schema File:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cart: {
        items: [{
            productId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true },
            quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
        }]
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The place where I use this schema to post something is that:-

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const product = new Product({
    title: title, price: price, description: description, imageUrl: imageUrl, userId: req.user
  });
  product.save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log('Created Product');
      res.redirect('/admin/products');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
};
```

This error occur when i set required: true in User Schema file. If i remove required: true, I am not getting any error but my userId pass as null. There is no userId I got.
so, I don't understand why this happening.

Comment: Can it be that `req.user` is the issue? Shouldn't it be `req.body.user`?

Comment: No, I use req.body.user but I am getting same error

Comment: What is the value you are getting in `req.body.user`? Can you `console.log` and check this.

Comment: The console value of ```req.user``` gives null and ```req.body.user``` gives undefined

Comment: Yes, since you mentioned `userId` as a required field in a `Product` it is giving error. Pass a valid value for `userId`. What is the `payload` you are testing this API with?

Comment: I post all files where I am using it. I you said I post the code of file where I create user

Answer (score 0):

You try to use userId: req.user. But to do that, first You have to add user to the request object. You can do this in middleware in express. Normally you must implement user authorisation in your project, and if the authorisation pass you can add user info to request object, if authorisation failed then must redirect to login page. But the best option for the moment to be sure that everything is OK change userId: req.user, with userId: existed userId from the database. In this case validation must be good.